# A curious way of generating series expansion for $\cos x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

If we take the approximation $\sin x  \approx x$, then, using the trigonometric identity $1- \cos 2x = 2\sin^2 x$, and take $2\sin^2 x \approx 2x^2$, we get, after making the substitution $x \to x/2$, that

$$\cos x \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$$

Now, using the trigonometric identity

$$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$

and using the last approximation  $\cos x \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$, then we get a new approximation for $\cos x$, namely

$$\cos(2x)\approx2\left(1-\frac{x^2}2\right)^2-1=1-2x^2+\frac{x^4}2$$

Then let $x\to\frac x2$ to get

$$\cos(x)\approx1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{32}$$

So, we repeat:

$$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1\approx2\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{32}\right)^2-1$$

and so on. This seems to generate a series expansion for $\cos x$, similar to Taylor's series, but with greater denominators.

The question is: Does the iterative procedure described above generates better and better approximations to $\cos x$, that is, a Taylor-like series one, or this iterative procedure doesn't converge to $\cos x$ to arbitrary accuraty for real $x$?

Comment: How exactly do you get $\sin x\approx x-x^3/8$?

Comment: $sin x = x$ is an estimate with some error, the error is small when $x$ is small.  The algebra you have done has indeed increased the precision of your estimate, but the Taylor polynomial $\sin x = x - \frac {x^3}{6}, \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac {x^4}{24} $ is a better estimate for the same degree of polynomial.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Use the second trigonometric identity, $\sin x \approx x$ and the approximation obtained for $\cos x$, and the map $ x  \mapsto x/2$

Comment: @DougM I know that Taylor's series are better, but what I want to see is a proof that the series generated by the above procedure indeed converges to the sine and cosine functions, if they do.

Comment: I'm guessing they don't converge to $\sin(x) $ and $\cos(x) $ , since from the first few terms $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ isn't satisfied.

Comment: You should specify your iteration procedure more clearly because I get a different result at the second step: $\cos x = 1-x^2/2+x^4/32-x^6/8192$ and $\sin x = x-5x^3/32+x^5/256$

Comment: @Raskolnikov I have edited the question. Can you look at it?

Comment: My first thought would be to see if I could prove that $f(x) \mapsto 2 [f(x/2)]^2 - 1$ is a contraction on $C [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, which would then imply that iterating it would converge uniformly to a unique fixed point function on $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$.

Comment: [I found a related paper.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0406049.pdf)

Comment: Repeatedly applying the double-angle formula to a Taylor or Padé approximation of the cosine is a known trick for numerics. See e.g. [this](https://doi.org/10.1137/0901013), where it is used for the *matrix* cosine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get weird coefficients for terms beyond $x^2$ because you re using an inaccurate input for the double angle formula.  If you have

$\cos x = 1-(x^2/2)+O(x^4)$,

you must accept

$\cos 2x = 1-(2x^2)+(x^4/2)+O(x^4)$;

and putting $x/2$ for $x$ then gives

$\cos x = 1-(x^2/2)+(x^4/32)+O(x^4)$

You did not make the error term any smaller in order of magnitude than the quartic term you added, so you cannot defend the quartic term.

How to get the right quartic term?  Assume

$\cos x = 1-(x^2/2)+(ax^4)+O(x^6)$.

Apply the double angle formula; after simplifying you get

$\cos 2x = 1-(2x^2)+((4a+(1/2))x^4)+O(x^6)$,

where everything that's a multiple of $x^6$ or a higher power is lost in the "noise" of the error term. Put $x/2$ for $x$ to then get

$\cos x = 1-(x^2/2)+((a/4+(1/32))x^4)+O(x^6)$.

This matches your original assumption if $a=(a/4)+(1/32)$; thus, properly, $a=(1/24)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just help me to understand this: 1) Your answer implies that, in fact, these weird coefficients makes this a non-convergent series for $\cos x$. 2) Also, with this correction, it is possible to obtain every correct term of the original series expansion. Is that right?

Comment: 1) the series might still converge but not to $\cos x$; 2) the corrected method will work for all terms.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little R program for your iteration. It represents the series as a sequence of their coefficients. I then define the effect of halving the input on the coefficients

```
halvearg<-function(x) ((1/2)^(0:(length(x)-1)))*x
```

and the multiplication of series

```
seriesprod<-function(x,y) {
    length(x)->n
    sprod<-rep(0,2*n-1)
    for (l in 1:(2*n-1)) {
        for (k in (max(l-n+1,1)):(min(l,n))) {
            sprod[l]<-sprod[l]+x[k]*y[l-k+1]
        }
    }
    return(sprod)
}
```

In principle, multiplication of series could be done by the `convolve` function in R, which uses the FFT. But it doesn't produce exactly the output I want, so I'll either have to write my own variant of `convolve` or try to adapt the existing one. For now, I just defined my own series multiplication.

Then, I apply your iteration scheme on the starting input

$$\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

which is represented as

```
x<-c(1,0,-0.5)
```

Here's the iteration

```
unit<-c(1,0,0)

for (k in 1:10) {
    unit<-c(1,rep(0,2*length(x)-2))
    x<-halvearg(x)
    x<-2*seriesprod(x,x)-unit
}
```

Notice I don't evaluate many steps, because the sequence grows very fast, indeed the length grows according to the recursion

$$\ell_n=2\ell_{n-1}-1$$

which is exponentially fast.

Here are the first 10 terms of the series, after those 10 iterations

```
[1]  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -5.000000e-01  0.000000e+00  4.166663e-02
[6]  0.000000e+00 -1.388882e-03  0.000000e+00  2.480126e-05  0.000000e+00
```

Here are the first ten terms of the actual Taylor series of $\cos$ for comparison

```
[1] 1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -5.000000e-01 0.000000e+00 4.166667e-02
[6] 0.000000e+00 -1.388889e-03  0.000000e+00 2.480159e-05 0.000000e+00
```

Not too bad. Here's a plot of the logarithm of the coefficients in blue at each step of the iteration. The red curve is the negative logarithm of the gamma or factorial function. You can see it converges pretty fast.

[image: Iteration convergence]